# Loop in Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I am not able to loop in jquery, I want different boxes to appear consecutively each after other. Right now they are displaying only once. Also I wants to fadein dark red box then fadeout dark red box, after it dark green fadein and fadeout dark green and consecutively every box in a loop and the whole process should work continously and when someone hover it should stop fading and start fading on mouseout. Please help me

Please find my codes below:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                function loop() {       
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.red_hover').delay(1000).fadeIn ({
                    }, 1000, "linear", function(){        
                    });

                    $('.red_hover').delay(1000).fadeOut ({
                    }, 1000, function(){        
                    });
                }, 1000);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.green_hover').delay(1000).fadeIn ({
                    }, 1000, "linear", function(){        
                    });
                    $('.green_hover').delay(1000).fadeOut ({
                    }, 1000, function(){        
                    });
                }, 4000);

                }
                loop();
            });
        </script>
```

CSS:

```
            <style>
                .red{width:100px; height:100px; background:#F00; float:left;  
                 overflow:hidden; position:absolute; margin:0 0 0 10px;}
                .red_hover{width:100px; height:100px; background:#900; float:left;  
                 overflow:hidden; position:absolute; margin:0 0 0 10px; display:none;}

                .green{width:100px; height:100px; background:#0C3; float:left;  
                 overflow:hidden; margin:0 0 0 120px; position:absolute;}
                .green_hover{width:100px; height:100px; background:#060; float:left; 
                 overflow:hidden; position:absolute; margin:0 0 0 120px; display:none;}

                .blue{width:100px; height:100px; background:#09F; float:left; 
                 overflow:hidden; margin:0 0 0 230px; position:absolute;}
                .blue_hover{width:100px; height:100px; background:#00F; float:left; 
                 overflow:hidden; position:absolute; margin:0 0 0 230px; display:none;}

                .yellow{width:100px; height:100px; background:#FF0; float:left; 
                 overflow:hidden; margin:0 0 0 340px;}
                .yellow_hover{width:100px; height:100px; background:#F90; float:left; 
                 overflow:hidden; position:absolute; margin:0 0 0 340px; display:none;}

                .pink{width:100px; height:100px; background:#FCF; float:left; 
                 overflow:hidden; margin:0 0 0 450px; position:absolute;}
                .pink_hover{width:100px; height:100px; background:#F0F; float:left; 
                 overflow:hidden; position:absolute; margin:0 0 0 450px; display:none;}
            </style>
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red_hover"></div>
            <div class="green"></div>
            <div class="green_hover"></div>
            <div class="blue"></div>
            <div class="blue_hover"></div>
            <div class="yellow"></div>
            <div class="yellow_hover"></div>
            <div class="pink"></div>
            <div class="pink_hover"></div>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lepw197v/

Comment: do u want to hide 1st div when 2nd fadesin n so on??

Comment: I don't see an actual loop occurring. You are just calling it once as it stands. A loop construct like for( var i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ){} would run your code 5 times if loop was inside of it

Comment: @Harsh Yes I want to hide 1st div when second div fadein

Comment: try this out http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/Lepw197v/1/

Comment: @Scott ok but what would be the variable for this ? Because every colour has a different class.

Comment: do u want this to happen continuously??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/40zurcvn/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny add this .`red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .pink{
    display:none;
}`

Comment: @Harsh Yes and stops when hover and start when mouseout

Comment: @Arun Its working continuously :)
Can u also tell me if it can stop on hover and start working againg on mousout

Answer (score 0):

I think you want "setInterval" instead of "setTimeout".

See this fiddle. It doesn't work perfectly but it's close to what you want I think.
    http://jsfiddle.net/bergonom/3bzfL87s/

HTML:

```
<div id="ColorBlocks">
<div class="red"></div>
            <div class="red_hover"></div>
            <div class="green"></div>
            <div class="green_hover"></div>
            <div class="blue"></div>
            <div class="blue_hover"></div>
            <div class="yellow"></div>
            <div class="yellow_hover"></div>
            <div class="pink"></div>
            <div class="pink_hover"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var redInterval, greenInterval;
                function loop() {       
                redInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    $('.red_hover').delay(1000).fadeIn ({
                    }, 1000, "linear", function(){        
                    });

                    $('.red_hover').delay(1000).fadeOut ({
                    }, 1000, function(){        
                    });
                }, 1000);

                greenInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    $('.green_hover').delay(1000).fadeIn ({
                    }, 1000, "linear", function(){        
                    });
                    $('.green_hover').delay(1000).fadeOut ({
                    }, 1000, function(){        
                    });
                }, 4000);

                }
                loop();

    $("#ColorBlocks").on("mouseover","> div", function() {
        clearInterval(redInterval);
        clearInterval(greenInterval);
    });

    $("#ColorBlocks").on("mouseout","> div", function() {
        loop();
    });
```

(Although your question and my response are getting downvoted for some reason. It would be nice if people explained why.)

Comment: I downvoted your original answer because all you wrote was a one-liner, saying 'I think you want "setInterval" instead of "setTimeout"' with no explanation as to why you 'think' this is better. As it was written, it was a poor answer, but much better now. However, I do feel `setTimeout` and `setInterval` can *both* be used here and I would actually prefer `setTimeout` for ongoing animations like this - the reason why is best explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/933633

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: Ironic that you downvoted me for a one line answer but you didn't initially even provide a single word as to why. That being said I appreciate your explanation after the fact.

Comment: Nothing ironic about that, *at all*. Cheers.

Comment: Well now you're just deliberately being incorrect. I'll know to ignore your responses in the future.

Comment: Now you're deliberately being childish. This is the very reason people don't like giving feedback on downvotes - becuase people like you cannot handle the critisism and end up wanting to argue over nothing. You just couldn't be a man and accept my feedback, could you? All you had to say was "thanks for the feedback". Grow up!

Comment: I can handle the criticism .. you didn't give me any! That's the whole point. You downvoted me without telling me why. I therefore had no information about to improve myself. When you finally did explain the downvote I said, and I quote, "I appreciate your explanation." It would be difficult for your last statement to be more incorrect.

Comment: Have a lovely day, Bergie.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/juz4jsx0/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      function loop() {   

        $(".red").fadeOut(function(){green()});
        $(".green").fadeIn();
      }
      function green(){
           $(".red").fadeIn();
           $(".green").fadeOut();
      }

       setInterval(function() {loop()},1000);

  });
```